# running a javascript code inside C++ without using system()

Tags: c++, node.js, abstract-syntax-tree

I've created a program which converts a sample javascript code to its AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) representation in javascript. The server part is implemented in C++(can't change it). So when the server is running I used system() to run the node program that does the conversion(ie, from javascript to AST). However, the system() is taking 80% of the total time. 
Is there any other way to run javascript code inside C++?

`C++ code
system("./bash_script.sh");`

```
bash code:
node convert_to_ast.js file_to_be_converted.js
```

Comment: While there is some overhead of using `system`, the majority of the time each call takes is the "program" it runs. If the script you call is taking a long time, then it will still take a long time no matter how you run it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Running the node program outside the C++ code took only 10% of the time it took to run the code inside the system().

Comment: How did you measure?

Comment: You want to run JavaScript code inside C++ code ??? Use V8 engine.  It is exactly the same engine that runs Node.JS.

Comment: If you want to learn how to embed V8 in a C++ program, try following this guide https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting%20Started%20with%20Embedding

Comment: _"Running the node program outside the C++ code took only 10% of the time it took to run the code inside the system()."_ I'll go so far as to say that this is not just highly improbable, but more or less impossible. You measured it wrong!